# How can I use slicing to find data that matches certain inequalities in a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a pivot table containing population data over several years.

I created this pivot table from extracting information from a data frame and using the .pivot_table command, where I assigned the index to be the year that each datapoint is from, and the columns in the pivot table are the population that was under the age of 18, and the total population. I tried to depict the table below:

```
aladata = 

       POPULATION
AGE    TOTAL         UNDER18
YEAR
1990 | 4050055.0   | 1050041.0   |
1991 | 4099156.0   | 1060794.0   |
...  | . . .       | . . .       |
2013 | 4833722.0   | 1111481.0   |
```

Using slicing, I want to find the years where the total population is less than a certain number BUT the under18 population is larger than another certain number. (Namely, 4.5M and 1.1M)

The original dataframe contained many data points for every state and territory, not just the one state I am concerned with. So I extracted the information related specifically to population, then set the DataFrame index to state, and used a query to create another dataframe containing only the Alabama data.

Now I need to find the years where TOTAL is under 4.5M and UNDER18 is over 1.1M, but I am required to use slicing to do so.

This is probably a very simple question, but I am only a few days into learning how to use Pandas.

Comment: Hi Bri! Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this a homework question?

Comment: also just as a general thing it would be good to provide an example where the thing you're looking for is possible to be found in the answer. There are no rows where TOTAL is under 4.5M and UNDER18 is over 1.1M

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) as well as [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).